# React Native TabView Swipe

Tags: react-native, tabview

Iam looking React Native swipe tabs. Right now using "React Native Tab View" it as an issue like lazy loading, flatlist won't work, Tab indicator get delay. please suggest a good package or how to do swipeable tab in react-native. Thanks

"React Native Tab View" https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view

Answer (score 2):

You can try [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view) . I have implemented in lot of projects and working fine

Comment: Hi Mehran, Thanks for the package.

Comment: I am not able to install this package

Answer (score 0):

You can try Material Top Tabs Navigator `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs`, more info at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator